# Need to format an array of objects in a different way

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have a matrix response array:

```
matrixArray = [
                {Responded: 1, RowName: row1, ColName: col1},
                {Responded: 2, RowName: row1, ColName: col2},
                {Responded: 0, RowName: row1, ColName: col3},
                {Responded: 0, RowName: row2, ColName: col1},
                {Responded: 0, RowName: row2, ColName: col2},
                {Responded: 1, RowName: row2, ColName: col3},
                {Responded: 1, RowName: row3, ColName: col1},
                {Responded: 0, RowName: row3, ColName: col2},
                {Responded: 1, RowName: row3, ColName: col3},
                ...
                ...
              ];
```

It tells that how many times a column has been responded for a row.
I need above array of objects in the following format:

```
matrixArray = [
                {
                  RowName: row1,
                  col1: 1,           //Here '1' is no. of times column responded
                  col2: 2,
                  col3: 0
                },
                {
                  RowName: row2,
                  col1: 0,
                  col2: 0,
                  col3: 1
                },
                {
                  RowName: row3,
                  col1: 1,
                  col2: 0,
                  col3: 1
                },
              ];
```

I am using TypeScript for this.
Thanks.

Comment: Please share your attempts.

Comment: You can edit your question. Also, as I said above, you're supposed to show what you tried before people help you. At least share what your approach is and what you can't figure out.

Comment: I've had an answer ready, I'm going to post it anyway before I lose track of it. Please make an effort to show your attempts next time.

Comment: Apologies @Jeto but had some connection probs so not able to post my attempts. I was making use of forEach and .filter on the array. My plan was to get the rows first in a different array, and then push the columns respective to it. But that plan didn't work actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Values) to obtain the desired result:

```js
const matrixArray = [
  {Responded: 1, RowName: 'row1', ColName: 'col1'},
  {Responded: 2, RowName: 'row1', ColName: 'col2'},
  {Responded: 0, RowName: 'row1', ColName: 'col3'},
  {Responded: 0, RowName: 'row2', ColName: 'col1'},
  {Responded: 0, RowName: 'row2', ColName: 'col2'},
  {Responded: 1, RowName: 'row2', ColName: 'col3'},
  {Responded: 1, RowName: 'row3', ColName: 'col1'},
  {Responded: 0, RowName: 'row3', ColName: 'col2'},
  {Responded: 1, RowName: 'row3', ColName: 'col3'}
];

const result = Object.values(matrixArray.reduce((result, entry) => {
  if (!(entry.RowName in result)) {
    result[entry.RowName] = {RowName: entry.RowName};
  }
  if (!(entry.ColName in result[entry.RowName])) {
    result[entry.RowName][entry.ColName] = 0;
  }
  result[entry.RowName][entry.ColName] += entry.Responded;
  return result;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Note that I didn't type the variables to make it runnable here, feel free to do so since you're using Typescript.

Explanation:

- `Array.reduce` loops over the array and builds a `RowName => {RowName, col1, col2, col3}` map (object) by incrementing by the corresponding `Responded` amount on each iteration),
- `Object.values` then transforms that back into an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) like this:

```js
const matrixArray = [{Responded:1,RowName:'row1',ColName:'col1'},{Responded:2,RowName:'row1',ColName:'col2'},{Responded:0,RowName:'row1',ColName:'col3'},{Responded:0,RowName:'row2',ColName:'col1'},{Responded:0,RowName:'row2',ColName:'col2'},{Responded:1,RowName:'row2',ColName:'col3'},{Responded:1,RowName:'row3',ColName:'col1'},{Responded:0,RowName:'row3',ColName:'col2'},{Responded:1,RowName:'row3',ColName:'col3'}]

const merged = matrixArray.reduce((acc, {Responded,RowName,ColName}) => {
       acc[RowName] = acc[RowName] || {RowName};
       acc[RowName][ColName] = (acc[RowName][ColName] + Responded) || Responded;
       return acc;
   }, {});

const output = Object.values(merged);
console.log(output)
```

Here's a shorter version of the above code:

```js
const matrix = [{Responded:1,RowName:'row1',ColName:'col1'},{Responded:2,RowName:'row1',ColName:'col2'},{Responded:0,RowName:'row1',ColName:'col3'},{Responded:0,RowName:'row2',ColName:'col1'},{Responded:0,RowName:'row2',ColName:'col2'},{Responded:1,RowName:'row2',ColName:'col3'},{Responded:1,RowName:'row3',ColName:'col1'},{Responded:0,RowName:'row3',ColName:'col2'},{Responded:1,RowName:'row3',ColName:'col3'}],
  
output = Object.values(matrix.reduce((a, {Responded,RowName,ColName}) => (
    (a[RowName] = a[RowName] || {RowName})[ColName] = Responded, a), {}));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: @Mr.A just a heads up: The accepted answer has the column names hard coded inside the `reduce`. It won't work if there's another column named `col4`.

Comment: @adiga Fixed that--I did suppose these columns were specific anyway. As a note, this one doesn't do well if several entries have the same `RowName` / `ColName` (in which case it would be logical to increment the `Responded` count each time). Not sure this is possible though (probably not!)

Comment: @Jeto Yeah, I'd have to add a ternary in between to handle that. Looking at OP's data, I assumed there won't be any duplicates for rows and columns.